# Problem installing Windows Server 2008 R2 on Xen 3.0

Tags: xen, windows-server-2008-r2

I've been googling this for a few hours now and not really getting anywhere.

We have a Xen 3.1.2 host which I'm trying to install a copy of Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition onto as a guest OS - but the install hangs at the "Starting Windows" screen when it starts running the installer.

Is this is a known issue with the version of Xen we're running (I know it's positively ancient)? Is there a workaround for it at all?

We've successfully got a great number of vanilla 2008 servers running on it, it appears it's an issue specific to R2.

Bryan

Update : Running an strace on the stuck VM shows :

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {386090, 691432304}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {386090, 691497191}) = 0
select(14, [8 10 12 13], [], [], {0, 10000}) = 1 (in [8], left {0, 0})
```

over and over, with the occasional :

```
read(8, "\1\0^^\1\1\0\"\31]\340.\10\0E\0\0n\0\0@\0\1\21\311\235\300\250\v\332\342^\1"..., 4096) = 124
```

I've no idea if that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good folks in #xen on freenode.net have told me that I need to be running at least Xen 3.4 or Xen 4.0 in order to install 2K8R2.

Thanks for your attention :)